# Scrolling behaviour conflicts with a child RecyclerView and a parent Viewpager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I have a vertical scrolling `ViewPager2` and the last children contains a `RecyclerView` scrolling on the same direction.

This is causing a conflicting behaviour, the `ViewPager2` always steal the scroll event when I am at the page containing this `RecyclerView`. The only way to make the scroll inside the `RecyclerView` is if I scroll really slow, if I make it fast, like a swipe event the `ViewPager2` gets scrolled and changes the page.

Currently I'm doing a fix that involves disabled the user interaction changing the flag `isUserInputEnabled` to false when the page of the `ViewPager2` changes to this page that contains the `RecyclerView`, but a generic solution from the framework would be welcome :)

Comment: Try to put your RecyclerView inside a `<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>` [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView)

Comment: ^ However, keep in mind that in doing so, your RecyclerView can no longer recycler views and will resort to a mere widget inflating all its content at once, for it no longer has control over the dimensions and it must delegate this to the NestedScrollView, which knows nothing about recycling a view.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue to yours and I found the answer via the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#nested-scrollables).

I would suggest NOT to place your RecyclerView within a NestedScrollView simply for the reason [Martin Marconcini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684/martin-marconcini) answered previously. This causes the RecyclerView to create ViewHolders for every single data item, with no regards to recycling them. That is obviously very inefficient.

Instead, Google provided a solution in their [ViewPager2 samples](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/master/ViewPager2) where they created a generic wrapper class called [NestedScrollableHost](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/master/ViewPager2/app/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/integration/testapp/NestedScrollableHost.kt) that you simply add to your project. Then you can wrap that RecyclerView with it, similar to below, to handle the intercepted touch/swipe events:

```
<NestedScrollableHost
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

    </NestedScrollableHost>
```

As noted by the documentation, this only works for immediate children of the ViewPager2, which in your case should work just fine.

Hope that helps!

Comment: anybody can provide java version of NestedScrollableHost class?

Comment: @AliZarei I made a Java version of it, you can find it here https://gist.github.com/KhaledAlharthi/e7e52cdf689295abb76b9437e1e02228

Comment: To future reader, do not use the java version above it is not the same as the Kotlin version and does not work properly on older devices. Save yourself.

Answer (score 3):

edit child of ViewPager as RecyclerView

```
(binding.viewPager.getChildAt(0)as RecyclerView).isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
```

it's worked for me

Comment: I believe I encountered this in the past and also google an answer like this.
And now I reencountered this, found your answer, and recalled that this is a solution! Great job, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Put your recyclerview inside NestedScrollView and set below property on recyclerview and

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

Try this or manage touch event on recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

I will stop scroll of `viewpaper2`:

```
mviewpager.setUserInputEnabled(false);
```