# Reflection vs. finding child view

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection

For the same reason described in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58415985/scrolling-behaviour-conflicts-with-a-child-recyclerview-and-a-parent-viewpager2), I want to get access to the `RecyclerView` inside a `ViewPager2`. This RecyclerView is not exposed in any way.

I kept the title deliberately broad, because my intention of this question is not to solve a specific question; the problem is solved. The ViewPager2 is mere an example. I want to know if there is an objective better long term approach.

One could:

- Use reflection to access the property `mRecyclerView`
- Find and cast a view child to `RecyclerView`.
- (Do not use `ViewPager2`, but use an `RecyclerView` and add a layout manager, snapping and paging manually; deemed out of scope for this question)

I'd say:

- The RV is fetched once, so cost is negligible
- `ViewPager2` is stable enough, that at least the name of the property or the amount of child views will not change.
- Both solutions hardcode knowledge of `ViewPager2` in the app it should not know

In this case, is one better than the other?

Comment: "ViewPager2 is stable enough, that at least the name of the property or the amount of child views will not change" -- I would not make either of those assumptions, between versions of the library. IMHO, a more stable assumption is: `ViewPager2` only has one `RecyclerView`. So, find the first `RecyclerView` child of `ViewPager2`. If you want to be really safe, find *all* `RecyclerView` children of the `ViewPager2`, and if the count is not 1, do something to warn you that the new version of the library that you adopted broke this assumption.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. I'll find a child view and add a test checking my assumption